# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException when invoking WSDL service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, travelport-api

I was looking to use the `Travelport Universal API` to develop a Flight Booking System, so i have used this Travelport Developers official link as reference:

[Getting Started for Travelport Developers](https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Getting_Started/Getting_Started.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7C_____0)

As the documentation referred:

> Travelport Universal API offers an array of travel content for air, hotel, car, and rail, including ancillaries (optional services). It also provides functionality to build complete traveler, agency, branch, and account profiles.

For be able to send requests and receive responses, we should ask for a `30-Day Trial Credentials for Travelport Universal API`, so i have asked for this and i have received my credentials, the credentials is composed about many things:

Universal API User ID

Universal API Password

Branch Code (TargetBranch) for ProviderName (ProviderCode)

A URL

I test this credentials, and i am sure they are working using a php file from the link below:

[TravelPort Universal API - Ping Request with PHP](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/web-development/php/travelport-universal-api-ping-request-with-php-curl.html)

I am trying to run the Travelport API in JAVA using eclipse, and i follow the steps mentioned in the below url:

[Setting up to work with Universal API](http://travelport.github.io/travelport-uapi-tutorial/lesson_1-1.html)

The configurations steps that i followed are :

I have linked the Apache CXF with Tomcat

I have imported the project from GitHub using this link:

[Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial](https://github.com/Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial/tree/master)

I have edited the ENDPOINT_PREFIX in WSDLService class with the url received from the 30-Day Trial Credentials for Travelport Universal API email response

I generated the client classes using WSDL, and i tried to invoke the service,

### But a error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:150)
    at $Proxy48.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.travelport.service.system_v9_0.SystemPingPortType_SystemPingPort_Client.main(SystemPingPortType_SystemPingPort_Client.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: Not Found' when communicating with http://localhost:8080/kestrel/SystemService
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1600)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1607)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1551)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1348)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    ... 2 more
```

Can anyone support me with the required steps that i should do for be able to test the Travelport API, so i can send requests and receive responses from the real data of Travelport?

Comment: The error message is incomplete without the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter connection endpoint after generation of java classes. At runtime this can be done with:

```
String endpoint = "https://emea.universal-api.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI";
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> reqCtx = provider.getRequestContext();
String connUrl = endpoint.endsWith("/")
            ? endpoint + connUrlSuffix
            : endpoint + "/" + connUrlSuffix;
reqCtx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, connUrl);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you try to connect to localhost on port 8080, but there's no service running.

Comment: Look at the error message. It tells you what's going wrong. Now the server is running but when requesting `http://localhost:8080/kestrel/SystemService` you get a HTTP 404 error indicating that the resource could not be found. My guess is that you probably have a misconfigutation at some place.

Comment: Look at the edit history. The question contained a `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` as cause, indicating a possible backend problem.